# How to switch to other apps/spaces when running full-screen game

Tags: macos, spaces, fullscreen

I did not noticed such problems with anything except some games. For example, i'm runnin Pillars Of Eternity atm, and if it's running fullscreen mode, i cannot switch to any other apps (i've tried alt-tab, cmd-tab, cmd-arrow, f11, custom spaces-switching shortcuts, touchpad gestures)

Also, in window mode, i can only switch using `alt-tab` (switching between apps within the same space) if i have other apps running in the same space. Other shortcuts are working only if i'm clicking outside the game.

El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ctrl-arrow keys? This will move you between the left and right spaces.

A similar question is also here:

[How to switch between fullscreen applications in OSX (Mavericks)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110291/how-to-switch-between-fullscreen-applications-in-osx-mavericks)

Comment: yes, i did. Sorry, forgot to mention that.